# Instruments bug or coding error?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks, instruments

A quick question from a beginner.

I'm doing an App for the iPhone and get the following message in Instruments when looking for leaks. Is there anything I have done wrong or is this just how it is? I had some memory leaks in my own library, but I took care of those. But how to solve this?

[alt text http://img231.imageshack.us/img231/7448/instruments.jpg](http://img231.imageshack.us/img231/7448/instruments.jpg)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just below this table there is a button called Leaked Blocks ; expand that and then check where exactly it is occurring

Comment: Found it, thanks. Must say it's not the most intuitive piece of S/W they have made...
Helps a lot though.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not releasing an array somewhere perhaps?

Are you testing on the simulator or on the device?

Comment: On the device. Had a previous issue with a leaking array, but then it said the app name for the library, so I was able to locate it and fix it.